# how to render useState values for only specific div (component)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I created a table with formulas and I wanted from each cell to show the results of the formula when `onBlur` and to show the formula itself when `onFocus`.

- but the problem is that when I click on any cell => the cell with the value `25` will be affected as well, despite I want the cell `25` or`"=age+3"` to be effected only when clicking it precisely (`focus on it`)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const table = [
  { id: 1, row: ["name", "age", "email",'formula'] },
  { id: 2, row: ["Ali", 23, "alisci@yahoo.com", "=age+3"] },
  { id: 3, row: ["alex", 22, "alexsci@yahoo.com",'22'] }
];
export default function App() {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const age = table[2].row[1];
  return (
    <table className="App">
      {table.map((item, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          {item.row.map((cell, index) => {
            return (
              <td
                onFocus={(e) => setFocused(true)}
                onBlur={(e) => setFocused(false)}
                contentEditable
                key={index}
              >
                {cell[0] === "=" & !focused ? eval(cell.slice(1)) : cell}
              </td>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}
```

[on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-breeze-wtlus?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to keep track of the row that has focused and do a comparison. Here is my attempt at this. I have changed the index for the `table.map` to be `rowIndex` and in your conditional render, I check if `focused` is set and if it equals to the `rowIndex`.

OnFocus function sets the `focus` to the correct row index and onBlur sets it to null

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-carson-2xy4x?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

`SOLVED`

- when focus I check if the cell start with `=` then I convert innerText to `text`
- when blur I check if the cell start with `=` then I convert innterText to `eval`

```
  onFocus={(e) => cell[0] === "=" && (e.target.innerHTML = cell)}
                onBlur={(e) =>
                  cell[0] === "=" && (e.target.innerHTML = eval(cell.slice(1)))
                }
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-breeze-wtlus?file=/src/App.js)